# Is it safe to integrate MVVM [angularjs,knockout.js]in MVC [JSF/spring]

Tags: angularjs, jsf, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, mvvm

Is it good practice to combine MVVM [angularjs,knockout.js]with MVC [JSF/spring].

1. Is it good way to control mvvm object/variables/ from inside JSF page.
   Lets say I have to update a dropdown list in angularjs model by using jsf controller to fetch list object and update angularjs dropdown model. Is this a clean way or a junk way or is it just a work around.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I don't really know JSF or Knockout. However, I can easily imagine that because both sides want to be in charge of viewed components, a component based framework like JSF or Wicket might have trouble playing together with Angular. A couple things come to mind:

- Why do you need the component framework from the server side? Why not use a request-based framework like Spring MVC or struts? They should work fine as they are just taking care of the overall page loading.
- You will probably be ok if you decide to use one technology to do one thing. For example, do your page containers with JSF, and everything inside the page with Angular. I think you'll be ok with that. Of course, you are losing a big part of the benefit of JSF.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually doing this right now. I can't say what the best practice is, but we found that we needed to be able to output dynamic HTML from the server, even if you have an MVVM framework in the front end. Things like internationalization is better handled on the server side, and with purely static HTML from the server you run into a lot of limitations.

The main drawback is complexity. You will have controllers, models and views on the server, combined with controllers, templates and viewmodels on the client. This makes the architecture a bit confusing, especially as you bring new members into the team, so documentation and code structure becomes *very* important.

Overall, I think it's a valid approach. It hasnt bitten us yet, at least :)